# Delete compressed file after extraction - how to set the default value?

Tags: compression, winrar

If I right click on a single RAR file  and click  : "extract files"

I can see this menu and already know how to delete the original compressed file :

[image]

But I have to set this setting each time I'm extracting.

Is there any way to default value a "yes" for future usages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "Save settings" button in the "General" tab.[image]